# No bullseyes in OpenCms8 - "Service implementation URL not specified"

Tags: opencms

In one of my test servers, I have a somehow corrupted OpenCms installation: after logging in, the ADE bar is empty and I cannot edit anything:

[image: ADE without bullseyes]

I don't get any kind of error or warning in the logs.

After some research, I found that in comparison to sane installations, this corrupt one is rendering a `Service implementation URL not specified` message in one of the divs that usually contains this bullseye (only relevant html shown):

```html
<body class="GMQ4TUIBKGB GMQ4TUIBFO">
   +<div id="window">
   +<iframe id="editprovider" src="javascript:''" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none;" tabindex="-1">
    <div style="display: none;"></div>
   -<div class="GMQ4TUIBLEB">
       -<div class="GMQ4TUIBJEB" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <div class="GMQ4TUIBEBB"></div>
           -<div class="GMQ4TUIBABB">
                <span class="GMQ4TUIBPAB"></span>
                <br>
                <span class="GMQ4TUIBCBB GMQ4TUIBN1 GMQ4TUIBE2">Service implementation URL not specified</span>
            </div>
        </div>
       +<div class="GMQ4TUIBMEB">
    </div>
</body>
```

Rendered with firebug:
[image: Service implementation URL not specified]

How can I fix this?

---

Envirnoment notes:

- OpenCms 8.04 (self-compiled from official sources)
- Tomcat 6.0.35
- I copied our operative OpenCms DB, that uses OCEE and configured it to not use any of the OCEE components for my testing environment. During this config phase, I'm afraid I have broken something.
- Our production DB is quite big (some 100 GB), and would like to avoid re-cloning it and installing OpenCms from scratch to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem **(re)installing the `org.opencms.ade.editprovider` module**:

[image: Bullseye restored]

Apparently I had a version mismatch between my *OpenCms 8.04* and the "inherited" OpenCms modules from the operative version. (In this case, *org.opencms.ade.editprovider 8.0.4* matches *OpenCms 8.0.4*.)